# Mono.NET error when starting with stack-mark=precise

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

When I attempt to start mono with `MONO_GC_PARAMS=stack-mark=precise` option, the app does not start up and it fails with the following error. Any ideas?

```
* Assertion at mini-gc.c:2036, condition `cfg->frame_reg == cfg->cfa_reg' not met
```

This is how I start it

```
$ export MONO_GC_PARAMS=stack-mark=precise
$ mono File.exe
```

The version of mono is 3.12.1 (latest)

Is this a bug? or am I doing anything wrong - don't have necessary dependencies etc.?

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: Mono version 3.12.1 (latest)

Comment: A quick search for that error shows that this is a known bug and has already been fixed. It wouldn't surprise me if it simply didn't make it into any release yet. It's not clear to me what you're asking here: is it a bug? Yes, assertion failures are always a bug. How to work around it? Don't, either compile Mono yourself from the latest sources, or wait for a version that has the fix (3.14?).

Comment: version after 3.12 will be 4.0 which is already branched

Comment: Yeah, I want to know if there is a workaround currently. I guess the answer is compile from sources. If you add it at the bottom, I will accept it. thanks.